# where a and b are positive integer and $\gcd(a,b) =1 $

Tags: number-theory

I've been thinking on this proof for 1 week.
show that,
$$ (2ab-a-b) \bmod (2a)= (a-1)b\,\bmod 2a $$
I would be happy if someone can help me.

Comment: Proof of what? Do you mean that $2ab-a-b\equiv (a-1)b\pmod {2a}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: he meant they have the same remainder when divided by 2a

Comment: YES I want to  prove that why have the same remainder when  divided by 2a. I've tried, but I'm facing difficulty. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to
$2a$ divides
$(2ab-a-b)- (a-1)b$.

But
$(2ab-a-b)- (a-1)b
=2ab-a-b-ab+b
=ab-a
=a(b-1)
$
and for this to be divisible
by $2a$
we need $b$ to be odd
(so $b-1$ is even).

For example,
if $a=3$ and $b=2$,
then
$(2ab-a-b) \bmod (2a)
=(2*3*2-3-2)\bmod (6)
=7\bmod (6)
=1
$
and
$(a-1)b\,\bmod 2a
=(2*2)\bmod 6
=
4
$.

Comment: yes, I  Assume that  b is odd and gcd( a, b)=1